# Generate `VertexId` from pairs of `String`

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm using GraphX to process some graph data on Spark. The input data is given as `RDD[(String, String)]`. I used the following snippet to map `String` to `VertexId` and build the graph.

```scala
val input: RDD[(String, String)] = ...

val vertexIds = input.map(_._1)
                     .union(input.map(_._2))
                     .distinct()
                     .zipWithUniqueId()
                     .cache()

val edges = input.join(vertexIds)
                 .map { case (u, (v, uid)) => (v, uid) }
                 .join(vertexIds)
                 .map { case (v, (uid, vid)) => Edge(uid, vid, 1) }

val graph = Graph(vertexIds.map { case (v, vid) => (vid, v) }, edges )
```

When I did a spot check to see the top 1000 highest degree nodes, I found the result of GraphX is different from the original input. Here's how I dump the high degree node

```scala
graph.outerJoinVertices(graph.outDegrees) {
  (_, vdata, deg) => (deg.getOrElse(0L), vdata)
}.vertices.map(_._2).top(1000).saveTo(....)
```

I suspect `.zipWithUniqueId` gives unstable ids for each evaluation. I tried

- insert `vertexIds.count()` to force materialization so that `vertexIds` doesn't get reevaluated.
- insert `.sortBy(...).zipWithUniqueId()` to make sure the ordering is the same.

Neither of them solves the problem. The results of top 1000 degree nodes differ slightly for each run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions to stabilize the `String -> VertexId` mapping:

- persist `vertexIds` to FS.

  ```
  input.map(_._1)
       .union(input.map(_._2))
       .distinct()
       .zipWithUniqueId()
       .saveAsObjectFile("some location")
  val vertexId = sc.objectFile("some location")
  ```
- use a collision-resistant hash function. I used [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html)'s murmur3_128 hash and took the first 8 bytes as vertexId. With this approach, you don't need to do any further joins, which is more efficient.

Comment: Just a note about the second approach you presented; One has to be careful with the manipulation of 64 bits ids coming from hashing function (from large hash truncated or from algorithms that natively produce 64 bits outputs). For example if you manipulate more than 100 million vertexes in your workflow, you will face a non-negligeable collision probability of ~0.1% (see [birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack)). Like you said the first approach is more computationally expensive but totally resilient to ids generation collisions, making it preferable for very large data